# Gmail API - Unable to list all mails by Labels

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

Hello and many thanks for your replies

I have begun my programming journey a couple of days ago just for fun, and because I have liked Python for a while now, but never actually took a chance to look into it or try to experiment with it.

A day ago it came across my mind what if I could download attachments from a specific set of emails by custom user labels, ie "MyEmail" or "EmailCool", and store all of the attachments that were under these labels.

I have experimented a bit with the Gmail API, and did some of the initial testing myself through: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list  but the problem being is that I can only grab and store attachments if I only specify one of the custom labels I had created ie "MyEmail" as a parameter.

If I input both of these labels as parameters, the API throws a response of resultSizeEstimate = 0, meaning as if there were no e-mails.

Is there anything wrong I am applying under the service.users().messages.list() method? Again my code works if I give one label as a parameter, but not two custom labels at the same time.

Here is my code, for your reference:

```
import base64
import email
import os
import requests
import google.oauth2.credentials
import pickle
import sys

from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient import discovery
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def ListMessagesWithLabels(service, user_id, label_ids):
  """List all Messages of the user's mailbox with label_ids applied.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    label_ids: Only return Messages with these labelIds applied.

  Returns:
    List of Messages that have all required Labels applied. Note that the
    returned list contains Message IDs, you must use get with the
    appropriate id to get the details of a Message.
  """
  try:
    response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,
                                               labelIds=label_ids,
                                               maxResults=500).execute()
    print(response)
    messages = []

    if 'messages' in response:
      messages.extend(response['messages'])

    while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']

      response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id,
                                                 labelIds=label_ids,
                                                 pageToken=page_token,
                                                 maxResults=500).execute()

      messages.extend(response['messages'])

      print('... total %d emails on next page [page token: %s], %d listed so far' % (len(response['messages']), page_token, len(messages)))
      sys.stdout.flush()

    return messages

  except errors.HttpError as error:
      print('An error occurred: %s' % error)

def GetAttachments(service, user_id, store_dir, label_ids):

    """Get and store attachment from Message with given id.

    Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: ID of Message containing attachment.
    prefix: prefix which is added to the attachment filename on saving
    """

    try:
        # email_list = ListMessagesWithLabels(GMAIL, user_id, [label_id_one,label_id_two])  # to read unread emails from inbox
        email_list = ListMessagesWithLabels(service, user_id, label_ids)

        for email in email_list:
            message_id = email['id'] # get id of individual message
            message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id).execute()

            for part in message['payload']['parts']:
                newvar = part['body']

                if 'attachmentId' in newvar:
                    att_id = newvar['attachmentId']
                    att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId=user_id, messageId=message_id, id=att_id).execute()
                    data = att['data']
                    file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('UTF-8'))
                    print(part['filename'])
                    path = ''.join([store_dir, part['filename']])
                    f = open(path, 'wb')
                    f.write(file_data)
                    f.close()

    except Exception as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)




# Setup the Gmail API
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', ]
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
mail_labels = ['Label_3679404043833618922', 'Label_7190264889161813326']

workingDir = os.environ['USERPROFILE']

gmailDownloadDir = os.path.join(workingDir, 'GmailDownload/')
attachDir = os.path.join(gmailDownloadDir, 'attachments/')
cred_file = os.path.join(gmailDownloadDir, 'credentials.token')
refreshtoken_file = os.path.join(gmailDownloadDir, 'refresh.token')

if 'GmailDownload' not in os.listdir(workingDir):
    os.mkdir(gmailDownloadDir)

if 'attachments' not in os.listdir(gmailDownloadDir):
    os.mkdir(attachDir)


# Get Gmail Credentials
if not os.path.exists(cred_file):
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
    credentials = flow.run_local_server()

    with open(cred_file, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(credentials, token)
else:
    with open(cred_file, 'rb') as token:
        credentials = pickle.load(token)

if credentials.expired:
    credentials.refresh(Request())

service = discovery.build('gmail','v1',credentials=credentials)

#GMAIL = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
#service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


GetAttachments(service, user_id='me', label_ids=mail_labels, store_dir=attachDir)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the link you posted, by `labelIds[]` it says

`Only return messages with labels that match all of the specified label IDs.`

So the email must have all labels in the list—not just any label.

An alternative is to use the `q` parameter with with something like `label:MyEmail or label:EmailCool or ...`

Check out this page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

That gets me one step closer. Now, I would not like to specify in my query all labels manually, I think there is no way to specify an array in the query, but that should be the least of my concerns.


I wil do some more testing and let you know

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you're right, specifying the label names manually would not be very useful. However, you can use [str.join(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to programmatically create strings from arrays

Comment: Hey folks. Just to give you an update. 

I was able to apply the filter by specifying all of my labels inside an OR for my query.


ie   query='{label:MyEmail label:EmailCool}'



That would be the best approach for what I need. Feel free to post any more replies as you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

you may your own labels if you sure about the names you can pass them over `lablelIds= []`, if your not sure about label names first list and choose from there what labels you want to use.

Gmail api ca able to get all the labels if you use `labels().list()` method use the below links as reference

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list

http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.users.labels.html#list

Comment: Yep that was my initial approach. I retrieved the label Ids I needed from the Google API runnable example from the links you shared but ultimately I found it easier to apply a filter and gather all of the labels inside an array and then converting the array as a string, and pass it as parameter to the users.messages.list() method